# OpenLDAP syncrepl with plaintext authentication

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to set up a syncrepl relationship between two openldap servers. The data they serve is not secret and they are used only in an enclosed network, so I'd like to avoid the hassle of setting up SSL. However it seems syncrepl refuses to work with a simple plaintext authentication. Is this correct, or am I being misled by some other authentication issue?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, yes in the end it turned out that syncrepl does require encryption.